# An integral converges- Analysis Fourier

Tags: fourier-analysis

I want to show that if $k\geq2$ and $f\in C_{c}(\mathbb{R})\cap C^k(\mathbb{R})$ then
$\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} |\xi|^{κ-2}|\hat{f}(\xi)|dm(\xi)<\infty$.

I can't understand what can i use for that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Integration by parts gives
$$
\widehat{f^{(k)}}(\xi)=(i\,\xi)^k\hat f(\xi)
$$
Since $f^{(k)}$ is continuous with compact support, its Fourier transform is bounded. Thus there exists a constant $C$ such that
$$
|\hat f(\xi)|\le\frac{C}{|\xi|^k}\quad\forall\xi\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
Let $R>0$.
$$\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} |\xi|^{κ-2}|\hat{f}(\xi)|\,d\xi&=\int_{|\xi|\le R} |\xi|^{κ-2}|\hat{f}(\xi)|\,d\xi+\int_{|\xi|> R} |\xi|^{κ-2}|\hat{f}(\xi)|\,d\xi\\
&\le2\,R^{k-1}\,\|\hat f\|_\infty+C\int_{|\xi|> R} |\xi|^{-2}\,d\xi\\
&<\infty.
\end{align}$$

Comment: I have reached to this step, my problem is how to continue. Thanks toy a lot

Comment: I have completed my answer.

Comment: You were very helpful.thanks you a lot

Comment: I think that we can directly bound the integral, i.e. $\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}|\xi|^{k-2}|\hat{f}|(\xi)d\xi\leq \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}|\xi|^{k-2}C\frac{1}{|\xi|^k}d\xi= \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}|\xi|^{-2}|d\xi$. Is this right?

Comment: No, the last integral diverges at $\xi=0$.